# Getting all Posts that belong to one User and display to pass to the view Node / Express / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below is the code for User model, Post model and the route. I need to query the DB and then pass to the view through the router. What am I missing?

User model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Posts model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema({
    postTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postStory: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

And here is the query in the router that I'm trying but apparently it's not the way to go...

My GET route:

```
router.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Post.find({author:req.user._id}, (err, posts) => {
       if(err) {
         console.log(err);
       } else {
         res.render('users/dashboard', {currentUser: req.user, posts: posts});
       }
    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change the `find` query to match the proper attribute in the following line:

```
Post.find({author: req.user._id}, (err, posts) => {
```

to be:

```
Post.find({'author.id': req.user._id}, (err, posts) => {
```

Read more: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html